# Can I deploy my angular application in intranet when I used angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

It seems the clients will try to access the Internet like googleapis, but the clients cannot access the Internet. So I want to pack the whole required resources to the server, how should I do?

Comment: How do you load Angular Material in your app?

Comment: I just follow the guide https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started.  I found it added `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">` in my index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to provide more details about what Google APIs your app tries to access but it's likely the URIs for Material Icons/Fonts.

[Here is some Google documentation](https://fonts.google.com/knowledge/using_type/self_hosting_web_fonts) about self-hosting the fonts.

Alternatively you can also think about installing a package like [material-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-icons)/[material-symbols](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-symbols) or hosting the files yourself.